# NumberPicker not showing numbers

Tags: android, styles, numberpicker

Im trying to create an `AlertDialog` with a `NumberPicker` inside it.
However it only displays the two dividers and no text.

See
http://imageshack.com/a/img673/8149/aWHQfj.png

Im using:

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

**code:**

```
    private void showInputDialog() {
    Context context = getActivity();
    RelativeLayout linearLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(context);

    numberPicker.setMaxValue(1);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(100);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    numPicerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.addView(numberPicker,numPicerParams);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Number of strokes");
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(linearLayout);
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            int score = numberPicker.getValue();

                            if (mRows != null) {
                                if (mClickedColIndex > 10) mClickedColIndex -= 1;

                                mClickedPlayer.setManualScore(mClickedColIndex, score);
                            } else {
                                if (mClickedRowIndex > 10) mClickedRowIndex -= 1;

                                mClickedPlayer.setManualScore(mClickedRowIndex, score);
                            }

                            mClickedText.setText(Integer.toString(score));

                            setupScorecard();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I've done many searches on the topic but i have yet not found any solution that works..

Also what's wierd i cant set: `android:numberPickerStyle` in styles.xml.

Anyone got any ideas about this?

Comment: I just noticed i had reversed min & max. Changing that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
numberPicker.setMaxValue(1);
numberPicker.setMinValue(100);
```

with this:

```
numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);
numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
```

Minimum value can not be higher than maximum value.